# How to separate columns with special characters in Pandas, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, special-characters

[image]

My data file contain some characters that can not be defined from keybord to set as separator. Is there  anyways to read this data in proper way.

My data looks different in .txt file but when I pasted here it looks like:

```
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
PW  100  2000  2000  C   0  0  0   0.00   0.00    0
```

But I have also attached original data here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QGe4wC-jrOnD08nBN4iXK-xbptOSzEt3/view?usp=sharing).

To read data, I simply tried by this way:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_table('data.txt',sep = '\s+')
```

is there better way to do that?

Comment: Try changing your `sep` to this: `r'[\s+\x00-\x19]'`

Comment: yea fixing it. realized the difference after OPs examples. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip your file from invisible characters:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import re

with open('pwd_data.txt') as fp:
    buffer = io.StringIO(re.sub('[\01-\03]', '', fp.read()))
    df = pd.read_table(buffer, header=None, sep='\s+')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    0    1     2     3  4   5   6   7    8    9   10
0   PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0
1   PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0
2   PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0
...
32  PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0
33  PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0
34  PW  100  2000  2000  C   0   0   0  0.0  0.0   0

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 35 entries, 0 to 34
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   0       35 non-null     object 
 1   1       35 non-null     int64  
 2   2       35 non-null     int64  
 3   3       35 non-null     int64  
 4   4       35 non-null     object 
 5   5       35 non-null     int64  
 6   6       35 non-null     int64  
 7   7       35 non-null     int64  
 8   8       35 non-null     float64
 9   9       35 non-null     float64
 10  10      35 non-null     int64  
dtypes: float64(2), int64(7), object(2)
memory usage: 3.1+ KB
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `[\x00-\x19]` instead of `[\01-\03]`, because there might be more than just 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I saw only three invisible characters from \x00 to \x03. I'm afraid \x19 is a bit too wide :)

Comment: I don't think it's too wide. `0x00` through `0x19` are control characters. The space character (`32`/`0x20`) is the first non-control character.

Comment: But maybe so... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your sep to `r'[\s+\x00-\x19]'`

```
pd.read_table('data.txt',sep = r'[\s+\x00-\x19]')
```

Comment: yes it works but gives lots of nan columns